# How to Create a ComboBox with a DataGrid Dropdown in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-interface, datagrid, combobox

I'm trying to rig up a ComboBox with a Datagrid dropdown in WPF. I need the the code to be done programmatically and contained in the codebehind.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
                        Dim cb As New ComboBox
                        Dim dg As New DataGrid

                        dg.AutoGenerateColumns = False

                        dg.ItemsSource = clnObjects 

                        Dim col_name As New DataGridTextColumn
                        col_name.Header = "Name"
                        col_name.Binding = New Binding("Name")
                        col_name.CanUserSort = False
                        col_name.CanUserResize = False

                        dg.Columns.Add(col_name)

                        Dim col_startdate As New DataGridTextColumn
                        col_startdate.Header = "Start Date"
                        col_startdate.Binding = New Binding("StartDate")
                        col_startdate.CanUserSort = False
                        col_startdate.CanUserResize = False

                        dg.Columns.Add(col_startdate)

                        cb.Items.Add(dg)
```

This code produces a ComboBox that contains a DataGrid with two columns and seems to look fine. Although when you click on the ComboBox and select one of the rows in the DataGrid the selection in the ComboBox doesn't work properly. (It just shows the colum headers.)
I want the value in the first column of the selected row to appear as the ComboBox selection.

If anyone can help me with this issue it would be greatly appretiated.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Why can you not use XAML to do this?

Comment: I'm creating the ComboBox at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your want your `ComboBox` to contain items from `clnObjects`, but to display the DropDown using a `DataGrid`, not the default`StackPanel`.

Right now your `ComboBox` is full of `DataGrid` controls, not whatever object is in `clnObjects`. This means when you select an item, you're selecting a `DataGrid`, not the `DataGrid.SelectedItem`

You could try changing it so the ComboBox's display text contains `ComboBox.SelectedItem.SelectedItem` where the first `SelectedItem` is the DataGrid, however I still feel this is a bad design since you need to create a new `DataGrid` object per `ComboBoxItem`

Instead I would recommend overwritting the default `ComboBox.Template` to display the ComboBox items in a `DataGrid` instead of in the default StackPanel. The default ComboBox Template can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx). Just copy it and replace the StackPanel with `IsItemsHost="True"` to a DataGrid

```xml
<Popup x:Name="Popup" ...>
    <Grid x:Name="DropDown" ...>
      <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" ... />
      <ScrollViewer ...>
        <!-- Replace this with a DataGrid -->
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
  </Popup>
```